# SSIS: Populating NULL instead of blank values in Excel Destination

Tags: ssis

I have a Data flow task where I am extracting an excel file from OLE DB source.

So my Control Flow is like File System Task => DFT(OLE DB Source => Excel Destination).

I have a template of excel file that gets copied by File system task and then the data is extracted from ole db soure to Excel file.

If there are blank values I need to populate them as NULL in Excel. How can I do that? I tried to use derived column but was not successful.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you want NULL or blank?  NULL means nothing in Excel.  If you want blank, in your query that populates the Excel do an ISNULL(col, '') AS COLNAME and it will give you blank instead of NULL.

Comment: "I tried to use derived column but was not successful." That's certainly one way to do it. In what way were you not successful?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a Data Conversion transformation task between the OLE DB source and the Excel destination where you can convert the columns that may contain blank values to a data type that allows NULLs, such as DT_WSTR for string columns.

In your Derived Column transformation task after the Data Conversion task, you can use the following :

```
TRIM(column_name) == "" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,50) : column_name
```